# How to take backups on a defined directory instead of creating sub-directories

Tags: sql-server, ola-hallengren

I am using Ola-Hallengren scripts and now I have a situation in which I require to take backups without creating sub-directories for each DB. I need to define a centralized path like `C:\Backups` for all FULL, DIFF and LOG backups.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change the Directory parameter in the Ola Hellengren script. Go to the job, click the Step --> Edit-->@Directory = 'C:\Backup',

This will be enough.

Adding to your particular requirement, I went into the Store proc and was able to figure out. This took me some time so apologies for that. Please mark this as answer once you are able to complete your task.

Below are the steps to get your required directory :

1. For getting all backups to just one location, you will need to remove few parameters from the store proc **[dbo].[DatabaseBackup]**. There will be this part where you set variebles( Look for the comments) -- Set variables
2. Go ahead and look for the below part :

> SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), DirectoryPath + CASE WHEN
>   RIGHT(DirectoryPath,1) = @DirectorySeparator THEN '' ELSE
>   @DirectorySeparator END + CASE WHEN @CurrentAvailabilityGroup IS NOT
>   NULL THEN @Cluster + '$' + @CurrentAvailabilityGroup ELSE
>   REPLACE(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('servername') AS nvarchar(max)),'\','$')
>   END + @DirectorySeparator + @CurrentDatabaseNameFS +
>   @DirectorySeparator + UPPER(@CurrentBackupType) + CASE WHEN
>   @ReadWriteFileGroups = 'Y' THEN '_PARTIAL' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN
>   @CopyOnly = 'Y' THEN '_COPY_ONLY' ELSE '' END, Mirror, ROW_NUMBER()
>   OVER (PARTITION BY Mirror ORDER BY ID ASC), 0, 0   FROM @Directories
>   ORDER BY ID ASC

3. Now you need to remove the parameters : @CurrentDatabaseNameFS and UPPER(@CurrentBackupType). This will create all your backups to a single location as below

[image: C:\Backup\LAPTOP-8BATS2T5]

Go through each of the available parameters in Ola hellengren scripts. [Ola Hellengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/)

Comment: Thank you Ramakant, for responding back. I tried above and its still creating sub-directories for each DB backup. I want all full, diff and log backups to be saved at one path like 'C:\Backup\ instead of having multiple sub-directories.

Comment: @Sourabh : I have jotted down the steps that you will need for your particular requirement. Please update the SP as mentioned above and you will be good to go.

Comment: The solution worked as expected and tested successfully, but I found that if Full and Diff backups are in the same directory and while passing parameter @Cleanup Time, it removes both  earlier Full and Diff backups (because of same file ext of .bak), even if you execute only Diff backup script as below: EXECUTE opsdb.dbo.DatabaseBackup
Databases = 'USER_DATABASES',
Directory = 'C:\DBBackup',
BackupType = 'DIFF',
Compress = 'Y',
CleanupTime = 192--0 Is there a solution for this as well, so that Full and Diff backups would be deleted separately.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly line 2285:

```
    -- JK 
    -- SET @CurrentDirectoryStructure = REPLACE(@CurrentDirectoryStructure,'{DatabaseName}',@CurrentDatabaseNameFS)
    -- SET @CurrentDirectoryStructure = REPLACE(@CurrentDirectoryStructure,'{BackupType}',@CurrentBackupType)
    SET @CurrentDirectoryStructure = REPLACE(@CurrentDirectoryStructure,'{DatabaseName}','')
    SET @CurrentDirectoryStructure = REPLACE(@CurrentDirectoryStructure,'{BackupType}','')
    SET @CurrentDirectoryStructure = REPLACE(@CurrentDirectoryStructure,'\\','\')
```